# How to convert string date in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, date, type-conversion

I have string like this:

```
 "/Date(1388521800000)/"
```

How would I convert it to "YYYY-MM-DD"?

Comment: `new Date(1388521800000)` and take what you need from the object.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can use this function to parse such date.

```
function fnParseDate(dateString)
{
    if (typeof dateString == 'object' && dateString instanceof Date) // It's already a JS Object (Of Date Type)
        return dateString; // No need to do any parsing. Return the original value.

    if (dateString.indexOf('/Date(') == 0) //Format: /Date(1320259705710)/
        return new Date(parseInt(dateString.substr(6), 10));

    alert('Given date is no properly formatted: ' + dateString);
    return new Date(); //Default value!
}
```

Comment: Given the OP, `new Date(+('/Date(1388521800000)/'.replace(/\D/g,'')))` is sufficient to create a suitable Date. Or `new Date(+('/Date(1388521800000)/'.match(/\d+/)[0]))`.

Answer (score 2):

If the String always looks the same I would parse it like this:

```
String date = "/Date(1388521800000)/";
String stamp;

stamp = date.substring(date.indexOf("(")+1, date.indexOf(")"));
```

Comment: It might help if you posted valid javascript.

Comment: Oh Sorry, I was firmly convinced you use Java, my mistake

Comment: Then you should maybe do ist like that:   
var date = "/Date(1388521800000)/";   
var a = date.split("(");   
var b = a[1].split(")");   
var stamp = b[0];

Answer (score 1):

```
var sDate = "/Date(1388521800000)/";
var date = new Date(sDate.match(/\/Date\(([0-9]+)\)\//)[1]|0);
var formattedDate = date.getFullYear() + "-"+ 
                   (date.getMonth()<9?"0"+(date.getMonth()+1):date.getMonth()+1)+"-"+
                   (date.getDate()<10?"0"+date.getDate():date.getDate());
```